# How to obtain the word vectors optimally

Tags: word-embeddings, bert, spacy

I have a list of strings as shown

```
sent_list = ["Carrefour is in France", "Apple pie is delicious", "Amazon has just delivered", ...]
```

My code to get word embeddings below

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg")

for sent in sent_list:
    print(nlp(sent).vector)
```

This takes considerable time when the list is of large size (>10000). I tried disabling `sentencizer` within the `nlp pipe` but with not much improvement. How can this be optimized for shorter run time?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nlp.pipe()` to process texts in larger batches, which is much faster, especially for a lot of short texts:

```
for doc in nlp.pipe(sent_list):
    # averaged doc vector
    print(doc.vector)
    # token vectors
    print([token.vector for token in doc])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `spacy` is known to be a bit slow. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913974/question-answer-model-for-polish-language/58914967#58914967) answer to similar problem. It'll be bit faster, once you run torch model under the hood. Additionally, you don't have to worry about language. You can easily detect it using libs like [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/). Language codes follow [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) standard, so no worries there too.